# html form save temp data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Hello guys I need your advice on best solution to my problem....

So I have simple html form which has input boxes, selects and stuff...

One of my select field generates its options from database an when user selects any option 3 input fields are filler automatically, problem is if value does not exist I have option value to create new. If user select this option javascript redirects to a new page where new option can be created and saved to database, after that user is redirected back to form however all fields that input fields have been filled now are empty....

What is the best way to save all input values user have entered so I can navigate user to different page where he can add item to the database and redirect him back to same form and fill all fields back?

First thing that I thought to put all input values to array and using php function http_build_query() send via GET and on redirection back send same array back, but form has like 20 fields and i believe it is not best solution as sending data take server resources...

Second, Put everything to json temp file, save on the server redirect user and on redirection back get this json file and fill data back and delete file afterwards... (I like this idea most)

Third, to create hidden form (like lightbox) show this form if needed, but here comes problem on this form submit it has to redirect somewhere if I redirect to same or different page I still lose all data...

Any idea guys?

Comment: Have you tried anything?, if so, post your code here.

Comment: I do not tried anything, now I am trying second one

Comment: In your third option you have specified that on this form submit it  has to redirect somewhere, if you are redirecting for saving the data then do it using ajax.

Comment: but after the select field still missing this option user just created and i need to refresh page for this as php function get data from database and fills dropdown again

Comment: you not need to refresh the page, return the newly added field details through ajax service page and append it to select box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case will better to use popup box (lightbox). Fill it with additional form and add event handler to it on form submit. Try to use event.preventDefault() inside the handler, then attach jquery.post method:

```
$( "#additional_form" ).submit(function( event ) {

  event.preventDefault();
  $.post('post.php', $('#additional_form').serialize());

  $(#lightbox).hide();

});
```

There's a lot of ways to do it, you can also just serialize it without sending. Or append it to your main form.

Answer (score 0):

Use the given codes

```
$("#additional_form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post('post.php', $('#additional_form').serialize());

  $(#lightbox).hide();
});
```